# Example when request.POST contain query string in django

Tags: python, django, post

Please post example code when request.POST contain query string in django, because i think my django version is bugged.

**EDIT:**

You simple can't, query string is always in GET, and this was my problem.

Comment: How about you post your code and then we can tell you what's wrong with it?

Comment: Ok, but i fight so long with this and nothing work so i try connect from another language to test django. Now i have little mess and need to clean it up, before i can show you simple version without not needed stuff.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your request is post:

> request.method == 'POST'

but the requested url contains a query string. e.g:

/your-url?param1=value-one

you can still take POST parameters through:

> request.POST.get("my-field", None)

and query string parameters through:

> request.GET.get("param1")

althrough, you pick up all parameters at once (POST and GET), through REQUEST:

> request.REQUEST['param1'] # comes from query string
>
> request.REQUEST['my-field'] # comes from request BODY (POST)

Comment: `request.REQUEST` has been [deprecated since v1.9](https://github.com/django/django/commit/75f107b8842dfc890ddd65262bd09ca87c3a15be)