# Create one endpoint with optional parameters and retrieve them when POST request

Tags: python, django, http-post

I know there are some previous posts about this on stack overflow, but nothing that matches what I am looking for.

```
    # urls.py
    url(r'^ror-sb/$', views.Ror_SBView.as_view(), name='ror-sb'),
```

Which means I can request my endpoint by accessing:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ror-sb/

My question is: I would like to create a POST endpoint where I can pass parameters through the URL. Some of them can be optional in my case...

Is there a way for me to get all the parameters from URL when a POST request is coming in?

Ideally, by requesting: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ror-sb/?test=True&toto=5&date=20191125
I can get:

- test -> True
- toto -> 5
- date -> 20191125

I am using django 2.6 and python 3.6

My view is quite empty for now:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class RorSBViewModel(TemplateView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.POST)

    return render(request, self.template_name)
```

By requesting: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ror-sb/?toto=2&test=5, my `request.POST` is empty...

Comment: You're doing a post request, so you don't need get query parameters, send post data

Comment: yes... sorry... So I can create my only endpoint: '^ror-sb/$', but how will you send parameters in your post request? Via json body ? And how to retrieve them from my django view ? - I am really new with Django (as you can see..).

Comment: There are plenty of resources on google if you search for `POST request` or similar, in django they'll be in `request.POST`, currently, your data is within `request.GET`

Comment: you can get your data from `query string` or `body` in post request.
and get your data : `request.POST.get("my-field", None)`

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961317/example-when-request-post-contain-query-string-in-django

Comment: In that case, I will send my post in json and get my params with ```request.body```. Thank you for helping. I was thinking everything should be under ```request.POST``` if this is a post and everything should be under ```request.GET``` if it s a get.

Comment: How do you test your application and send `POST` requests? Do you use jQuery, curl, Postman?

Comment: For testing I use Postman, once deployed, I will call this endpoint using curl. For now, my solution is to send the request via JSON body and deserialize and use it. Endpoint is: ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/ror-sb/``` and result of my ```request.body``` is my json payload

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('/jquery/submitData',   // url
       { todo:2,test:5 }, // data to be submit
       function(data, status, jqXHR) {// success callback
                console.log(data);
        })
```

You can send post request in jquery hit,